# Find where a certain string of numbers occurs using Regex

Tags: python, regex

Out of a large text file I want to extract all the places where "RA"+6 numbers after it occur. How would I do this?

For instance, I want the new txt file to look like

```
RA000000  
RA111111  
RA222222  
RA333333  
RA444444
```

Where other instances of RA do not show up either.

Comment: what have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
import re

with open('input.txt') as input_file:
    ra_list = re.findall(r'RA\d{6}', input_file.read())

with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write('\n'.join(ra_list) + '\n')
```

Tested input:

```
hello
RA111111 goodbye
RA2222 RA333
abcRA45678912345
```

Result:

```
RA111111
RA456789
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex is '^(RA\d{6})$'. Then print each time the capture group 1 was found.